# Ion-item content slides under ion-item-options before closing

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

When I slide my ion-item to close (to the right), the content slides under the ion-item-options before closing. This results in a poor UX experience as it does not look like a smooth transition. It is not working as it does in the ionic docs. How can I fix this so that when the user slides the item to close (to the right), the options (the icons) disappear before the content gets to it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The background of the ion-item was transparent. Setting it to a solid color did the trick.